# explode в Yii2 не записывает в бд

Tags: php, yii2

Текстовое поле TextArea, введен текст через запятую надо их разбить по строками и записать в базу, я так делал

```
$tagname=explode(",",$_POST['Tag']['tag_name']);
foreach ($tagname as $tags) {
    $tag->tag_name=$tags;
    $tag->save();  
}
```

здесь разбивает текст, но не записывает в базу.

Comment: а модель где инициализируется? `$tag = new Tag();`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы инициализируете модель за приделами цикла, то все время будите обновлять только одну запись в базе, для сохранения нескольких, инициализируйте модель внутри цикла.

```
if(isset($_POST['Tag']['tag_name'])){
    $tags=explode(",",$_POST['Tag']['tag_name']);
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tag = new Tag();
        $tag->tag_name=$tag;
        $tag->save();  
    }
}
```

P.S. Могут быть так же ошибки сохранения, проверяйте `$tag->getErrors()`

Comment: Этот метод пробовал он сохраняет только последнюю часть строку а мне нужен каждая строка.

Comment: Что значит "последнюю часть строку"? У вас строка вида - `"тег1, тег2, тег3"` - код выше должен создать три записи в базе данных с каждым тегом, `запись1->tag_name = тег1`, `запись2->tag_name = тег2`, `запись3->tag_name = тег3`. Если у вас что то не сохраняет то смотрите ошибки после сохранения модели.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего подключить уже готовое одно из готовых решений, например https://github.com/LAV45/yii2-target-behavior

Answer (score -1):

Еще момент, в модели БД в `rules` должно быть хотя бы одно правило валидации для `tag_name` - `string`, `safe` или любое другое.